# Tunnel openvpn ports

Tags: openvpn, tunnel

I have two VPS with Linux Ubuntu 18.04 OS,

One in our country with limited internet = VPS_1

One in EU with full access internet = VPS_2

I want to create OpenVpn server on VPS_2 and Forward OpenVpn ports on VPS_1.

If this is impossible,is there any way to create OpenVpn server on VPS_2 and connect VPS_1 to VPS_2 and create another openvpn server on VPS_1 that VPS_1 can access to all internet, and client connect to VPS_1 with OpenVpn?

This is a tunneling for openvpn.

I mention that I want to use UDP Ports for openvpn and

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:1194:DES_IP:1194 user@PASS
```

didn't work!

In our country, they limit us but we can access VPS_1 and VPS_1 can access to VPS_2 and VPS_2 have internet.

Can you explain how can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question is unclear - especially the first sentence and meaning of "connect to the last VPS openvpn).  Also, do you have to use OpenVPN? Wireguard has a lot fewer gotchas, so may be easier.   Also, what OS's are involved,?

Comment: I changed all text of question, Thank you

Comment: @davidgo Yes I have to,they filtered all protocols and I created wireguard or shadowsocks proxy but we couldn't connect to them!